# calculate width and height of a scaled div

Tags: javascript, math

I am scaling (resizing) a div on mousemove, I am also maintaining aspect ratio of the div. I can scale it as I wanted. I need to calculate the width and height of a scaled div.

Suppose if I scaled a div by some value d in picture, I need to calculate the width and height of div.

Also the div may already be in a rotated position, I have the angle as well.

I dont want values of getBoundingClientRect().

I think the problem is more mathematical.

[image]

Comment: There's no question here, just a vague description of some situation.

Comment: @goodvibration Question is the question marks in the pic, values of w and h for the scaled div.

Comment: What is d?``````

Comment: @MBo d is the distance or difference between top of div before scaling  and top of div after scaling